# How to change tab in the Flutter Default Tab Controller?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter Default Tab Controller for shows the tab View. And I need to change the tab while clicking the button, I tried to change tab using setState, but I faild. These are my codes:

```
   class _TabPageState extends State<TabPage> implements TabView {
  int tabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      initialIndex: tabIndex,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: TabBarView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('to Tab 3'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        tabIndex = 2;
                      });
                    }),
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.red),
            Container(color: Colors.yellow),
            Container(color: Colors.cyan),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
          labelColor: Colors.black45,
          tabs: [
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12), child: Text('green')),
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12), child: Text('red')),
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12), child: Text('yellow')),
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12), child: Text('cyan')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd say use a `TabController` instead of the `DefaultTabController`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this without stateful widgets by retrieving the controller with `DefaultTabController.of(context)` and then calling `.animateTo(index)` on it.

```
class TabPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      initialIndex: tabIndex,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: TabBarView(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: GoToThirdTabButton(),
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.red),
            Container(color: Colors.yellow),
            Container(color: Colors.cyan),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
          labelColor: Colors.black45,
          tabs: [
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12), child: Text('green')),
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12), child: Text('red')),
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12), child: Text('yellow')),
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12), child: Text('cyan')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GoToThirdTabButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('to Tab 3'),
      onPressed: () {
        DefaultTabController.of(context).animateTo(2);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The button must be its own widget so the `context` it sees will have the tab controller attached to it.

Comment: In the first line of your answer you have "DefaultTabController.from(context)" instead of "DefaultTabController.of(context)", typo perhaps?. unless that is a syntax change in a new version of flutter?

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo. I've fixed it now.

Comment: if my defaultTabController is for a tabview that's further down the list and I would like the page to be scrollable, where can I insert the SingleChildScrollView? Bcos when I inserted the SCSV above the scaffold, the page returned empty.

Answer (score 3):

## Code Golf Solution

If you want to access the DefaultTabController without creating an entirely new StatelessWidget, you can add a Builder widget to add a new context layer. This makes it so your button can "see" the DefaultTabController:

```
Scaffold(
body: SafeArea(
  child: DefaultTabController(
    initialIndex: 0,
    length: 3,
    child: Builder( // Add this
      builder: (context) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            TabBar(
              controller: DefaultTabController.of(context),
              labelColor: Colors.black,
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'One'),
                Tab(text: 'Two'),
                Tab(text: 'Three'),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(child: Center(
              child: OutlinedButton(
                child: Text('Three'),
                onPressed: (){
                  DefaultTabController.of(context)?.animateTo(2);
                },
              ),
            ))
          ],
        );
      }
    ),
  ),
),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabExampleState createState() => _TabExampleState();
}

class _TabExampleState extends State<TabExample> {
  var tabIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var childList = [
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('to Tab 3'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  tabIndex = 2;
                });
              }),
        ),
      ),
      Container(color: Colors.red),
      Container(color: Colors.yellow),
      Container(color: Colors.cyan),
    ];

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      initialIndex: tabIndex,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: childList[tabIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              tabIndex = index;
            });
          },
          labelColor: Colors.black,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(text: 'Green'),
            Tab(text: 'Red'),
            Tab(text: 'Yellow'),
            Tab(text: 'Cyan'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if my defaultTabController is for a tabview that's further down the list and I would like the page to be scrollable, where can I insert the SingleChildScrollView? Bcos when I inserted the SCSV above the scaffold, the page returned empty.